# django - query for specific thread with particular user

Tags: django, multithreading, django-views

I am creating a messaging system. Suppose A (sender) sends a message to B (recipient). I want to check whether there is already a thread with only those two, ie A and B. And if there is select that thread, and create a message with that thread. Otherwise create a new thread and add those A & B to that new thread, and then create the message with that new thread.

models.py

```
class Thread(models.Model):

    # subject = Name of the Users / Or Group name if given
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    # Below line may not be neccessary if we can get the MessageState of all the messages for this Thread as hidden for a user.
    # is_hidden = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='hidden_thread', blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):

class Message(models.Model):

    # To which thread the message belongs to
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)

    # Who is sending the message (or the active user who is creating the message to the reciepient)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)

    # When the message was sent
    sent_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    body = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-sent_date']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s - %s" % (unicode(self.thread.id), self.body, self.sender)
```

views.py

```
def private_message(request):

    # Get the sender
    sender = request.user

    # Get the recipient to whom it is being sent
    recipient = request.POST.get('recipient','')
    recipient = User.objects.get(id=recipient)


    # Get the subject of the message
    subject = request.POST.get('subject','')

    # Get the message body
    body = request.POST.get('message','')


    # Creating the thread with the above info
    thread = Thread(subject=subject)
    thread.save()

    # Attaching members to the thread
    thread_member1 = thread.user.add(sender)
    thread_member2 = thread.user.add(recipient)

    # Create the message from the above info
    message = Message(thread=thread, sender=sender, body=body)

    # Create a MessageState of the above message
    message_state1 = MessageState(message=message, user=sender)
    message_state2 = MessageState(message=message, user=recipient)
    message_state1.save()
    message_state2.save()
```

I tried filtering using the contains, but it didn't help me. Please kindly help me solve this problem. I will be very grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty complicated one, you have to filter the thread to get only those with 2 users, then filter with the sender and the recipient :

```
thread = Thread.objects.annotate(count=Count('user')).filter(count=2).filter(user=sender).filter(user=recipient)
if len(thread) is not 1:
    thread = Thread(subject=subject)
    thread.user = sender
    thread.user = recipient
    thread.save()
```

Comment: Am getting an error
`AttributeError: type object 'Thread' has no attribute 'annotate'`

Comment: @Kakar: Code fiexed, added an objects in the query

Comment: You can't get the same error, because you're no longer using the annotate method of Thread but you're using the annotate method of the objects manager.